# How to publish a basic message to RabbitMQ exchange using op-rabbit

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka

I've been trying to get a very simple app working to publish messages to a RabbitMQ exchange using the Scala op-rabbit library to no avail.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but the docs are very limited regarding message publishing.

I can get the actor to connect to RabbitMQ. However, upon publishing a message, it doesn't appear in Rabbit.

Here is the code I'm using to publish the message:

```
object RmqPublisher extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("my-actor")
  private lazy val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

  val rabbitControl: ActorRef =
    actorSystem.actorOf(Props {
      new RabbitControl(
        ConnectionParams.fromConfig(config.getConfig("op-rabbit.rabbit"))
      )
    }
    )

  rabbitControl ! Message.exchange("Test", "amq.direct", "my_routing_key")
}
```

Here is my config:

```
op-rabbit {
  topic-exchange-name = amq.direct
  channel-dispatcher = "op-rabbit.default-channel-dispatcher"
  default-channel-dispatcher {
    # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
    type = Dispatcher

    # What kind of ExecutionService to use
    executor = "fork-join-executor"

    # Configuration for the fork join pool
    fork-join-executor {
      # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
      parallelism-min = 2

      # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
      parallelism-factor = 2.0

      # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
      parallelism-max = 4
    }
    # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
    # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
    # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
    throughput = 100
  }

  rabbit {
    exchange-name ="amq.direct"
    routing-keys = "my_routing_key"
    virtual-host = "/"
    hosts = ["localhost"]
    username = "guest"
    password = "guest"
    port = 5672
    ssl = false
    connection-timeout = "5s"
    max-tps = 1000
  }
}
```

The logs suggest it is connected successfully as can be seen below:

```
[INFO] [08/04/2020 21:49:39.219] [my-actor-op-rabbit.default-channel-dispatcher-5] [akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection/$a] akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection/$a connected
[INFO] [08/04/2020 21:49:39.223] [my-actor-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection] akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection connected to amqp://guest@{localhost:5672}:5672//
[INFO] [08/04/2020 21:49:39.230] [my-actor-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection/confirmed-publisher-channel] akka://my-actor/user/$a/connection/confirmed-publisher-channel connected
```

[image: RabbitMq Overview]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are your exchanges stats look the same? Because you send to the exchange, but it might have no connected queues or the message have the wrong routing key or something. And also - have you checked that the admin panel and app connection relate to the same rabbitmq installation?